# Cancelling custom CoroutineScope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(
        Job() + Dispatchers.Main
)
scope.launch {
    beforeExecute()
    val result = withContext(dispatcher) { doInBackground(*params) }
    if (!isCancelled) {
        postExecute(result)
    } else {
        cancelled(result)
    }
    status = Status.FINISHED
}
scope.cancel()
```

If i put `scope.cancel()` outside launch it cancels the coroutine immediately without calling launch block code.Is this expected?Why it happens?Should cancel be placed inside launch at end of launch block if i want coroutine to end once it finish executing code inside launch?

**Update**

As per  Hau Luu's answer and Marko Topolnik's comment,

> ”at the end of launch, I think the task is done and you don't need to
> manually cancel the Coroutine.”

and

> “Once your task is done, the coroutine disappears from memory.”

But here in Case 2 ,if I start another  launch it is executed unless we cancel the coroutine inside first launch as in Case 1.
So is there any surety that after task is completed the coroutine disappears from memory without us manually calling cancel() ?Bcoz compiler will never know which is the last launch that is going to execute after which it needs to end coroutine

**Case 1**

```
scope.launch {
    Log.e("Task","1");
    scope.cancel()
}
scope.launch {
    Log.e("Task","2");
}
```

Only Task 1 is printed

**Case 2**

```
scope.launch {
    Log.e("Task","1");
}
scope.launch {
    Log.e("Task","2");
}
```

Both Task 1 and 2 are printed

Comment: You shouldn't cancel the scope unless object that's executing this coroutine is disposed of and its result is no longer relevant. What did you expect to happen if you cancel scope immediately after posting launch block onto it?

Comment: @Pawel i want that once my task is completed then coroutine should stop running.AFAIK lifecycle of coroutine depends on the scope we using like if i am using built-inscopes like viewmodelscope then lifecyale is tied to lifecycle of viewmodel.But here i am using custom CoroutineScope.How can i ensure that coroutine doesn't remain in memory once my task is done?I am using this code inside abstract class final method and my task finishes after `status = Status.FINISHED` line.

Comment: As you've said, viewmodelscope is tied to lifecycle of viewmodel so you should tie your scope to lifecycle of your class. Declaring scope for one coroutine execution makes no sense. If it's static method then you might as well just post it on `GlobalScope` because coroutines don't linger in memory once they finish executing.

Comment: @Pawel i believe GlobalScope is tied to lifecycle of application and should not be used!

Comment: I think @AndroidDeveloper has a point. A custom CoroutineScope will be tied to the lifecycle of the object that created it. So If you don't call scope.cancel at some point in time. The CoroutineScope instance will stay there until the object that is housing it is dead. But please keep in mind that a Coroutine and a CoroutineScope are 2 different things. A Coroutine will end its life after the Job we gave it ended.

Comment: @HauLuu Thanks for detailed explanation. If i create a CoroutineScope inside a method of a class using following code- `val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main )` ,then can i expect this CoroutineScope will be automatically destroyed once the method terminates?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper your question leads to another question. How can I check the existence of a given CoroutineScope? Let me do some research first. But in my opinion, the CoroutineScope won’t be terminated along with the method that created it. You just lost the CoroutineScope’s refs. The CoroutineScope will be terminated automatically when there is no active coroutine (CoroutineScope.isActive = false) and nobody holding a refs to it.

Comment: @HauLuu if I am creating coroutinescope inside a method then nobody can hold refs to it outside method.So that should mean that coroutine scope should be terminated along with the method that created it?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper yeah! In theory, it should be. But since  i have no way the check the existence of a CS (CoroutineScope) so i can’t confirm it. Because the life of coroutines inside a scope might be longer than the life of the method that start it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be translated to natural language as "Cancel the given coroutine right after scope.launch is executed" so I think this is expected behavior.

And for the other question, we only want to cancel a coroutine when there is something wrong during the execution process - hey coroutine, during the execution of the task I gave you. if there is sth wrong happen. Kill yourself. So at the end of launch, I think the task is done and you don't need to manually cancel the Coroutine.

Update: I write this as an answer because I can't write code in comment.

CoroutineScope was designed to react to the lifecycle of the object that create/start/house a coroutine. So when you call the cancel method on a CoroutineScope, you're stoping everything. Stoping not canceling. All child coroutines that were created by the scope, all jobs they are executing, cancel them all, and nothing more. The job is done. That's is why you can't start another launch after scope.cancel

A CoroutineScope will create and hold refs to a bunch of Corrountine via builder methods like launch and async. When you want to cancel a specific Coroutine. You need to cancel the Job that returned by the builder. Not cancel the scope that is housing them.

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html

```
val job1 = scope.launch{ print('Task 1') }
job1.cancel()
val job2 = scope.launch{ print('Task 2') }
```

Task 2 will be printed as normal.

Comment: AFAIK lifecycle of coroutine depends on the scope we using like if i am using built-inscopes like viewmodelscope then lifecycle is tied to lifecycle of viewmodel.But here i am using custom CoroutineScope.How can i ensure that coroutine doesn't remain in memory once my task is done?i believe i need to use cancel for that!

Comment: Once your task is done, the coroutine disappears from memory. It's pretty much the same as a `Thread` in this respect. You wouldn't do `thread.start(); thread.interrupt();`, and the same is true for coroutines.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can compiler  know which is the last launch that is going to execute after which it needs to end coroutine?Please check "Update"  part in my question based on your comment and Hau Luu's answer

Comment: Do you perhaps think that `scope` is the coroutine? `CoroutineScope` is nothing but a simple data object, it holds no resources. `launch` creates a coroutine, and when it's done, it disappears. Use `scope.cancel()` only when you want to abruptly cancel all the coroutines that happen to still run within the scope because the lifecycle of some component in your application is ending.

Comment: I've updated my answer since the editor for comment is quite hard to use. Sorry!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for detailed explanation. If i create a CoroutineScope inside a method of a class using following code-
`val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main
)`
,then can i expect this CoroutineScope will be automatically destroyed once the method terminates?

Comment: No, nothing will happen automatically. Even if you lose all references to the scope object, the scope won't be cancelled through finalization. BTW you don't need `Job()` inside the call, that's added automatically.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Do we need to do anything special with clearing of the scope, like scope = null? Example, if I create a scope, coroutine inside it executes and finishes, no more coroutines are active in it and nothing is holding references to that scope anymore, will GC clear it or we need to null it or something?

Comment: @Torima GC can't possibly clear an object that is still reachable. However, the `CoroutineScope` object usually owns very little data -- typically just a `JobImpl` object (which isn't associated to any coroutine) and a reference to a shared dispatcher. The main duty of `JobImpl` is to hold its child jobs -- of which in your case there aren't any.